# Python3 has no acces to python2 modules (ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, installation, python-2.x

Im fairly new to programming and Ubuntu. Yesterday I finally managed to create a dual-boot system, so now I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
For a school project, I need to work in Python3 with a module called SPARQLWrapper (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SPARQLWrapper).

On my freshly installed Ubuntu, I've installed the latest version of Python. When I type "python3" in my terminal, python 3.2.3 starts so thats good.
I installed easy_install (sudo apt-get install python-setuptools), and downloaded and installed the SPARQLWrapper egg file (sudo easy_install SPARQLWrapper-1.5.2-py3.2).

If I run python2 and use "import  SPARQLWrapper", it just works. But if I try the same in python3 it gives me the following error:

```
x@ubuntu:~$ python3
Python 3.2.3 (default, Oct 19 2012, 20:10:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import SPARQLWrapper
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named SPARQLWrapper
```

So my problem is that python3 isn't able to acces the same modules as my python2. How do I fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To install packages for Python3, you need python3's setuptools.

Following are the steps to be followed to install python3's setuptools and `SPARQLWrapper`

1. `sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools`
2. `sudo easy_install3 pip`
3. `pip -V` This should show the pip corresponding to your python3 installation.
4. `sudo pip install SPARQLWrapper`

After doing the above mentioned steps, I get this

```
~$ python3
Python 3.3.1 (default, Apr 17 2013, 22:30:32) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import SPARQLWrapper
>>> exit()
~$
```

Comment: On my system (ubuntu 16.04) pip for python3 is invoked with "pip3"

Answer (score 1):

Each Python installation has its own modules directory. In addition, Python 3 is not backwards compatible and won't generally run Python 2 code. You'll need to find a Python 3 version of the module you need and install it for Python 3.