# Why do I have problems loading a module in Python3 but not in Python2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04

Depending on which installation of Python I am using I have some problems to load a module. When I type

```
from quantecon import approx_markov
```

in the terminal using Python 3.4.0, the following error message is returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/quantecon/__init__.py", line 6,in <module> 
    from asset_pricing import AssetPrices
ImportError: No module named 'asset_pricing'
```

In the folder /usr/... as referred to above, I do however find a module called `asset_pricing`. (I have to admit that I additionally do not understand why the module `asset_pricing` interferes.)

I installed `quantecon` with:

```
pip3 install quantecon
```

I suspect that the problems are related to the Python version I am using. I also installed

```
pip install quantecon
```

and when I call the module `approx_markov` form the terminal, using Python 2.7.6  (I think this is the standard Python version of the OS I am using) I do not receive any error message. To solve the problem I already followed the instruction in the following discussion but to no avail  [Python3 has no acces to python2 modules (ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709914/python3-has-no-acces-to-python2-modules-ubuntu).

Comment: Thank you for editing, Martijn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The currently released version of `quantecon` is not Python 3 compatible; it uses relative imports and these are not supported anymore in Python 3.

The version in [the source repository](https://github.com/jstac/quant-econ) has been refactored and updated, and looks like it'll work with Python 3. You'll need to install that version instead:

```
pip3 install -U git+https://github.com/jstac/quant-econ.git
```

where `-U` tells `pip3` to upgrade the package.

Note that there have been a [lot of changes recently](https://github.com/jstac/quant-econ/compare/0.1.3...4b19c1b); use at your own risk. You *could* stick with Python 2 and wait for an official release.

Comment: Might be wise to use python 2.x if possible as many of those changes were only committed recently and there might still be outstanding (and unknown) bugs.

Comment: @Dunes: which is why I said *[it] looks like it'll work*. Yes, there is a caveat that the repository is still under heavy development.

Comment: I know, it just thought it was a point worth stressing to someone who might not be as familiar with python as you are.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Martijn. As quantecon was already installed I had to upgrade it. I modified your code as follows:     "pip3 install git+https://github.com/jstac/quant-econ.git -- upgrade". Can you please tell me how you knew that quantecon is not compatible with Python3 ? How do I recognize such limitations in general?

Comment: @fabian: adding in the `-U` switch will tell `pip` to upgrade. :-)